# How can a numpy array be both F-contguous and C-contiguous at the same time?

Tags: python, numpy

I 'm working on the below simple numpy array to understand strides. However I came across an output in its `.flags` that doesn't make sense to me.

```
> print(a)
[[100 200  50 400]
 [ 50   0   0 100]
 [350 100  50 200]]

> a.ravel()
array([100, 200,  50, 400,  50,   0,   0, 100, 350, 100,  50, 200])

> print(a.flags)
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False

> abytes=a.ravel().view(dtype=np.uint8)
> print(abytes)
[100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 200   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  50   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0 144   1   0   0   0   0   0   0  50   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0 100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  94   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
 100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  50   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 200   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0]

> print(abytes.flags)
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

How is `abytes` both F and C Contiguous ? I also do not understand how such an array operates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A one-dimensional array (shape is `(n,)`) is always both C and F contiguous.

Comment: Further from the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) of `ravel`: Return a **contiguous** flattened array.

Comment: Great. But if that is the case always, I wonder why  ```ravel``` has the _order_ parameter.

Comment: the `order` parameter determins in which order the elements of the multidimensional array are **read** in order to make a 1D array out of it. In any case the output will be a contiguous flattened array where the notion of order is pointless.

Comment: `a.ravel` will be different depending on the order parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, a 1-D array is both F-contiguous and C-contiguous. `a.ravel` creates such an array. To understand the concept of argument `order` in `np.ravel()`, this example might help:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

a
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]

a.ravel(order='C')
[0 1 2 3 4 5]

a.ravel(order='F')
[0 3 1 4 2 5]
```

As you can see in this example, when `order='C'`, it reads each row and stacks them to make a 1-D array, while, in case of `order='F'`, it reads each column and stacks them to create the 1-D array. Regardless of the `order`, the output is a 1-D array which is always both C-contiguous and F-contiguous.